# The type could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I Have .NET core project, which I build by dotnet. Then I do dotnet store and dotnet publish after build. "Test.dll" is generated in runtime package storage and in publish folder after it. When I run "dotnet MyProject.dll" I get an exception during builder.Build():

*System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'TestModule, Test' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly".*

**MyJsonFile.json**

```
{
    "modules": [
     {
        "type": "TestModule, Test",
        "properties": {
            "PluginInstanceNames": [ "Test" ]
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

**MyProject.cs**

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configBuilder.AddJsonFile("MyJsonFile.json");
var configModule = new ConfigurationModule(configBuilder.Build());

builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(configModule);
builder.Build();
```

Why it does not search modules from .json file in runtime package storage? How does it work?

It works only if I added this callback function, where "path" is string array with path to runtime storage folder and publish folder.

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (context, name) =>
{
     var dll = Array.Find(path, f => f.EndsWith(name.Name + ".dll"));
     if (dll == null)
     {               
         return null;
     }
     Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dll);
     return assembly;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is not responsible for assembly loading, the .NET framework is. Loading assemblies in .NET Core is different than in classic .NET framework on the desktop and does require additional work as you've seen. [There's an issue here (closed) in Autofac.Configuration](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/issues/31) explaining that; and we have a [currently open issue to document this in more detail](https://github.com/autofac/Documentation/issues/101) but the long and short of it is: You'll need to do work yourself with the `AssemblyLoadContext` just like you've done if you're loading plugins.